# PHP and MySql hitcounter problem?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I'm new to php and mysql I tried to build a web page hit counter but my page counter dosen't update correctly and it gets the following warnings listed below.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Here is the php code below.

```
<?php

$page = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; 

// Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id page FROM mysql_counter_logs WHERE page = '$page'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO mysql_counter_logs (page) VALUES ('$page')");
    mysqli_query($dbc);
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 1) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE mysql_counter_logs SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE page = '$page'");
    mysqli_query($dbc);
}

//Retreives the current count
$count = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT hits FROM mysql_counter_logs"));

if (!$dbc) {
    // There was an error...do something about it here...
    print mysqli_error();
} 


//Displays the count on your site
print "$count[0]";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extract of your code :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO mysql_counter_logs (page) VALUES ('$page')");
mysqli_query($dbc);
```

First of all, according to the manual of [mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query), when used as a function :

```
mixed mysqli_query  ( mysqli $link  , string $query  [, int $resultmode  ] )
```

Which means you have to pass your `$mysqli` variable as first parameter, and your query as a second parameter.

What I don't get is why you are using `mysqli_query` this way on the third line I copy-pasted, while you are using it correctly in the other parts of your code ?

Are you sure you mean to use that function, here ?

Also, knowing on which lines you are getting those error messages might help ;-)

Check you don't do anything else "wrong" there -- like " *mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given* "

Thinking about it : [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) will return boolean `false` if there is an error.

In that case, you should not call `mysqli_num_rows` on the return value of `mysqli_query`, as it's not a valid `mysqli_result` -- hence the second error message.

You are checking for `$dbc` at the end of your script, but it might be interesting to check it too a biit sooner -- actually, after each call to `mysql_query`, I'd say.

Also, as a sidenote : you probably don't need to instance the mysqli class that many times : just instanciate it once, and then use the `$mysqli` variable for there rest of your script.

Just for security, and to avoid any trouble, you might also want to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on the `$page` variable, before injecting it into the queries.

Oh, and, btw : you might be interested by the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) that MySQL allows to use ;-)

*(Well, that is if `page` is the primary key of your table, at least...)*